# Day high low Mid 25, 75

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to plot the 25 and 75% line to a script. I tried adding the same command that I used to get the middle (50%) line but I go the following error. Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr1'='m'. An argument of 'plot' type was used but a 'series float' is expected. I have this current script that correectly plot the 25 and 75% lines;

```
[D_High, D_Low, D_50, D_75, D_25] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [high, low, hl2, (high+hl2)/2, (low+hl2)/2], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Reg Sess High", style=plot.style_circles, color=#ff0000, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_75   : na, title="Reg Sess 75%",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#b2b5be, linewidth=1) 
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_50   : na, title="Reg Sess Mid",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_25   : na, title="Reg Sess 25%",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#b2b5be, linewidth=1) 
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_Low  : na, title="Reg Sess Low",  style=plot.style_circles, color=#ff0000, linewidth=1)
```

but I do not like using this one because it only shows the current lines and not where they used to be. I like using the following script because it shows where the past lines were during the day whereas the top script just shows the current high, low mid lines without the past historical lines. I like seeing where the support and resistance could possibly be at during intraday. Can someone help me with this dilemma please?

```
//@version=5

indicator("oldcyd Regular Session High Low Mid", overlay=true)
t = time("390", session.regular) // 390=60*6.5 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter
//plot(t, style=linebr) // debug

is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

day_high = float(na)
day_low = float(na)

if is_first and barstate.isnew
    day_high := high
    day_low := low
else
    day_high := day_high[1]
    day_low := day_low[1]

if high > day_high
    day_high := high
    
if low < day_low
    day_low := low
    

plot(day_high, style=plot.style_circles, color=#ff0000, linewidth = 1, title="Reg Session High")
m = plot((day_low + day_high) / 2, style=plot.style_circles, color=#ffeb3b, linewidth = 1, title="Reg Session Mid")
plot(day_low, color=#ff0000, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth = 1, title="Reg Session Low")
plot((day_low + m) / 2, color=#ff0000, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth = 1, title="Reg Session Low")
plot((day_high + m) / 2, color=#ff0000, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth = 1, title="Reg Session Low")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what the problem is.
You're saying on the 4. line from the bottom:

```
m = plot((day_low + day_high) / 2 ...)
```

Then you're trying to add to your float day_low and day_high `day_low = m` so basically `float + plot`

```
plot(day_high)
plot(day_low + (day_high - day_low) / 2)
plot(day_low)
```